# module name overloading and import path

Tags: module, import, twisted, testcase, trial

The code below fails because twisted.trial.unittest.TestCase, the desired baseclass, is not the baseclass.

```
from twisted.trial import unittest
from unittest import TestCase
import myapp

class Feature(TestCase):

  def setUp(self):
    self.callbackCounter = 0

  def checkCbCalled(self, expected):
      self.assertEqual(self.callbackCounter, expected)

  def testTrialCallsDeferred(self):

      d = myapp.buildFeature()
      self.addCleanup(self.checkCbCalled, expected=1)
      def cb(res):
        self.callbackCounter += 1
      d.addCallback(cb).addErrback(self.fail)
      return d           # does not fire because of 'import rules'?
```

If I had said

```
from twisted.trial import unittest as trialut
from trialut import TestCase
```

or, better:

```
from twisted.trial.unittest import TestCase
```

then the test would run as expected and trial.unittest.TestCase would have fired my deferred.

This seems as though the local recently imported thing should have superceded the one available in {lib/pythonX.X/unittest}. I understand it must be a rule based on sys.path or something else implicit or explicit. This tripped me up for a little too long because I did not have the call to addCleanup and all tests were passing because returned deferred instance was not being fired.

I broke some rule(s), Please advise some reading or other.

Thanks
Mike

Comment: I'm surprised that `from trialut import TestCase` works.  Does it work with `from __future__ absolute_import`?

Comment: @jrennie.  The reason this doesn't work is that, while the local name "trailut" is bound to the unittest module, python's imports don't look at local names when importing things, just actual modules and "trialut" isn't an actual module in sys.modules or its search path.

Answer (score 2):

It's very unclear how you expect this to work, but it sounds like you're at least somewhat confused about how modules in Python behave.

An `import` statement (sometimes) loads a module from a source file and then binds a name in the local scope to that module object.

So, when you do:

```
from twisted.trial import unittest
```

You're loading the `twisted.trial.unittest` module and then binding the local name `unittest` it.

This interacts in no interesting way with the following statement:

```
from unittest import TestCase
```

which loads the `unittest` module and then binds the local name `TestCase` to the object referred to by that module's `TestCase` attribute.

When you later subclass `TestCase`:

```
class Feature(TestCase):
    ...
```

you're making straightforward use of the name `TestCase` in your local scope - a name which refers to the `TestCase` class defined by the `unittest` module.  Notice that it has nothing at all to do with Twisted's `twisted.trial.unittest` module, even though you've loaded that module too.  You have to use one of its attributes in order to use its functionality.

One change to make to improve the behaviour of your code is to simply stop using the standard library`unittest` module at all.  Delete this line:

```
from unittest import TestCase
```

And replace your class definition with:

```
class Feature(unittest.TestCase):
```

Don't get confused by the fact that the standard library `unittest` module shares part of the name of the Twisted `twisted.trial.unittest` module.  They are different modules with different (though similar, sometimes overlapping) features.  The class definition in the example above is using `twisted.trial.unittest`, because it comes after your original line:

```
from twisted.trial import unittest
```

Once you are actually using Twisted's `TestCase` (from `twisted.trial.unittest`) and not the standard library's `TestCase` (from `unittest`), you'll get the behaviour you expect when a test method returns a `Deferred`.  This is because it's Twisted that provides this feature, not the standard library.

Comment: I think a slight clarification is needed.  The statement that "This interacts in no interesting way with the following statement" may be misleading.  By loading twisted.trial.unittest, the actual python unittest module gets loaded (have a look at sys.modules['unittest']).  So, while the initial load binds to the local name _unittest_; the subsequent "from unittest import TestCase" doesn't actually load the _unittest_ module (it's already been loaded).  It simply looks up TestCase in the-already-loaded _unittest_ module, and binds the local name TestCase to it.

Comment: That's true, but I don't think that discussion of whether an import statement actually loads and executes code to initialize a module, or merely pulls an already initialized module out of sys.modules will help the OP much, at least not until he gets past his current misunderstanding about modules.

Comment: Fair enough JP!  When working out this question, I actually found it somewhat disconcerting that unittest was in sys.modules right after importing unittest from twisted.trial (until I figured out that twisted.trial's unittest was in turn importing the standard one).

Comment: The main code I entered does not work as expected - This is intentional in pointing to the question. The third (better) code expresses the solution. The whole question is around local-name/module resolution. The main/first block of code expresses the confusion I created by assuming the local-name unittest would refer to module referenced by local-name 'unittest' created by importing twisted.trial.unittest. Since the confusing code expresses TestCase actually in local-namespace does not refer to the local-unittest but refers instead to the unittest that trial.unittest loaded from lib/pythonX.X,

Comment: Are you saying my answer doesn't address your question?  Or what?  Unfortunately, I have about as much difficulty understanding this comment as understanding the original question. :(

Comment: Comment from @Gerrat Jan 6 at 20:04 seemed to get to the point of the matter very succinctly. I think your answer is to a question I did not ask 'why is this code not working' since it starts out with a somewhat aggressive 'dont know how you expect this to work'. The answer to the 'how to make the code work' is placed later in my post   .

Comment: I'm sorry you thought my answer was "aggressive".  It wasn't meant that way.  I still don't know what question you're asking, though.